# Inappropriate ads on this site

Tags: discussion, advertising

There are ads on this site that say

> Find single matures in your area

Why?

Comment: If you see this again please let me know!  There is testing that is happening now and some ads slip through occasionally.  We've been able to target and continue to remove those that are inappropriate.  The one you report here definitely falls into this category.

Comment: Hey Brianna, welcome to SFF SE (and meta SFF.SE). You may find adblockers like [uBlock Origin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UBlock_Origin) and judiscious use ofscript blockers like [NoScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoScript) to be *quite* useful w/r/t ads in your web browser.

Answer (score 17):

A couple months ago, Stack Exchange decided to try out ads across the network. Some inappropriate stuff slips through sometimes. In that case, per [the official announcement](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/329763/398063), please report it as follows:

> If you wish to report an advertisement, please take a screenshot of the ad and paste the URL (if possible) along with the site where you saw it to a comment or answer. I'll report it to the ads team and we can track it down to investigate.

In the meantime, given how intrusive some of these ads can be ([remember this?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/331960/398063)), you may want to use an adblocker.